# Segmentation fault in strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I keep getting that error. I am pretty sure it has something to do with memory allocation but i'm not quite sure how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

char * VOWELS ="aeiouAEIOU";


void printLatinWord(char *a);


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char phrase[100];
    char *word = malloc(sizeof(char) *100);

    printf("Enter the phrase to be translated: \n");

    fgets(word, 100, stdin);
    printf("The phrase in Pig Latin is:\n");
    word = strtok(phrase, " ");
    printLatinWord(word);

    return 0;
}

void printLatinWord(char *word){
    while (strchr(VOWELS, *word) == NULL){
    char consonant = *word;
    char *to=word, *from=word+1;

    while (*from)
         *to++=*from++;
         *to=consonant;
    }
    printf("%say\n", word);
}
```

the out put gives "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: While this isn't an answer, you should really learn how to use [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdb/) as it will allow you to see exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: How far does it get before it seg faults? Do the other `printf` statements get executed? Might want to use a debugger to step through.

Comment: This looks a bit spurious: `char *word = malloc(sizeof(char) *100);`.  You then reassign `word` with the return value of `strtok()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fgets(word, 100, stdin);
word = strtok(phrase, " ");
```

You have the parameters the wrong way round here. You're splitting the string in `phrase` which is uninitialized, and then you're assigning the result to `word` thus overwriting the pointer to the memory you previously allocated.

You probably intended for the `fgets` to read the input into `phrase` rather than `word`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to allocate memory for `word`. After calling `strtok` it will point to the data inside the `phrase` buffer.